# Hosting multiple customer websites on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

We currently host a large number of containerized websites in Kubernetes and we are exploring using Google App Engine to host these sites but we cannot figure out how to host a large number (hundreds) of websites in a single Google App Engine account.

At first glance it seemed that every website will be a separate project but then it became clear that there is a soft limit of twenty projects (and we might end up hosting hundreds of sites) so this did not seem to be the correct approach.  We then explored using a single project with dispatch.yaml to route between the sites.  Dispatch.yaml only allows for ten entries which mean that it will not work.  Is there any other approach we are missing? Our dispatch.yaml routing looked like this:

```
  - url: "example2.com/*"
    service: my-second-website
```

None of the options we explored provided a scalable or viable solution. Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Kubernetes makes a lot more sense for hundreds of websites. Put each website into a container. Then you can run Apache or Nginx or basically any Linux webserver. Kubernetes will manage everything and scale automatically.

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution for this? The solution proposed by @Andrei seems plausible , but it comes with the price of needing to deploy 100's of services each time there is an update as noted by Alex. Also it might cost since each service will run its own instance if the traffic/load isn't huge on the already running instances. I wonder if it also possible to map a specific domain to each of the services

Comment: @Khaled - we ended up not using AppEngine for this.  Currently we host sites using a combination of Kubernetes for some dynamic sites and more recently a more powerful solution built using Google CDN, LoadBalancer and Firestore - this last solution is pretty powerful but took some time to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is one App Engine instance with multiple services (one for each website) and multiple versions in each service (if needed).

e.g:

```
App Engine instance
    ├── website01-service
    │   ├── website01-version01
    │   ├── website01-version02
    │   └── website01-version03
    │
    └── website02-service
        ├── website02-version01
        ├── website02-version02
        └── website02-version03
```

This is an example setup from [Quickstart for Python 3 in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine) documentation.

1. Download the files from git repository as stated in [Download the Hello World app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart#download_the_hello_world_app) section.
2. Copy the `hello_world` sample files in two different directories. e.g. **website01** and **website02**.
3. You should have something like this:

```
├── website01
│   ├── app.yaml
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── main_test.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── website02
    ├── app.yaml
    ├── main.py
    ├── main_test.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

4. In `website01/app.yaml` add `service: website01` and in `website02/app.yaml` add `service: website02`. This will deploy each app in different App Engine service.
5. In `website01/main.py` change `return 'First website!'` and in `website02/main.py` change `return 'Second website!'` (This is just to confirm after deployment that 2 different websites are running).
6. In the `/website01` directory execute `$ gcloud app deploy --version website01-version01` and in `/website02` directory execute `$ gcloud app deploy --version website02-version01`
7. After a successful deployment, you should see 2 different versions running in **Google Cloud Console > App Engine > Services** page.
8. When clicking on both links new tabs will open and you will see your two different websites running in the same App Engine instance with two different links. The links should appear as following:

```
website01 -> https://website01-dot-[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/
website02 -> https://website02-dot-[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried requesting that your project limit be increased? I think that's the only good way to make this work.

> If you attempt to exceed your project limit, the console will prompt you to fill out a request form. This happens when you try to create a project but you have already reached your quota. The form will require you to specify the number of additional projects you need, along with their corresponding email accounts, billing accounts, and intended uses.

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en

You *could* do this with a single project & single service/app.yaml, if your ok with the url for each website being something like :

1. www.website1.com/website1/
2. www.website2.com/website2/
3. www.website3.com/website3/
4. etc

Then you could use the `handlers` in `app.yaml` to do the routing (along with some light server code to redirect if someone tries to visit `www.website1.com/website2/`). The biggest issue with doing it this way is every time you'd deploy you would be deploying all 100 of your sites.